# How to prevent temporary files from being removed?

Tags: package-management, administration

I have Ubuntu 14.4 on my machine, and also have downloaded Android-SDK on it.

When I install some package in Android-SDK, it does three things:

1. it downloads the package into a temp folder,
2. when the download is completed, it unpacks that package into appropriate folders, and
3. it deletes that package from the temp folder.

What I wish to do is to keep that package located in the temp folder, since I'm going to install another version of Ubuntu, and do not want the packages to be downloaded again.

What can I do to prevent those temp packages from being removed?

There is something I should say: Android-SDK probably uses a specific command to remove the temp packages. If I can figure out that command, and I alias the command, then the SDK wouldn't be able to remove package files anymore. I know that command `rm` is not the command of my purpose, since I've aliased it, and the SDK still was able to remove packages. How can I find the command the SDK uses?

Comment: The package manager will not use your aliases. An alias is only available in your current interactive session, not in non-interactive shell sessions that _may_ be started by another process.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK isn't using a "command". Most probably it uses the unlink system call.

Try the same approach with the unpack process instead .